# adding values based on date range sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-range

Stuck on the problem below.

```
Current data: table1

|emp_id | date     | day_one |week_num |
 --------------------------------------
|    100|2021-01-01|     TRUE|        1|
|    100|2021-01-02|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-03|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-04|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-05|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-06|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-07|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-08|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-09|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-10|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-11|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-12|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-13|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-14|     NULL|     NULL|
 --------------------------------------
```

Desired output:

```
|emp_id | dates    | day_one |week_num |
 --------------------------------------
|    100|2021-01-01|     TRUE|        1|
|    100|2021-01-02|     NULL|        1|
|    100|2021-01-03|     NULL|        1|
|    100|2021-01-04|     NULL|        1|
|    100|2021-01-05|     NULL|        1|
|    100|2021-01-06|     NULL|        1|
|    100|2021-01-07|     NULL|        1|
|    100|2021-01-08|     NULL|        2|
|    100|2021-01-09|     NULL|        2|
|    100|2021-01-10|     NULL|        2|
|    100|2021-01-11|     NULL|        2|
|    100|2021-01-12|     NULL|        2|
|    100|2021-01-13|     NULL|        2|
|    100|2021-01-14|     NULL|        2|
 --------------------------------------
```

The data has many employees across thousands of dates so it needs be done in a way where weeks are added based off the day_one column. I have used a lag/lead but if an employee has an 8 week cycle it becomes very inefficient. The code below gives the week_num =1, repeating gives 2 etc.

```
with t1 as (
select 
    *
    ,
    LAG(week_num) OVER(PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY emp_id, dates) as second_day,
    LAG(week_num, 2) OVER(PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY emp_id, dates) as third_day,
    LAG(week_num, 3) OVER(PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY emp_id, dates) as forth_day,
    LAG(week_num, 4) OVER(PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY emp_id, dates) as fifth_day,
    LAG(week_num, 5) OVER(PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY emp_id, dates) as sixth_day,
    LAG(week_num, 6) OVER(PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY emp_id, dates) as seventh_day
from table1 
)
select 
    emp_id,
    dates,
    day_one,
    case when week_num = 1 then 1 
         when second_day = 1 then 1 
         when third_day = 1 then 1 
         when forth_day = 1 then 1 
         when fifth_day = 1 then 1 
         when sixth_day = 1 then 1 
         when seventh_day = 1 then 1 
         else NULL 
    end as week_num
from table1
order by emp_id, dates
```

And level 2 to the problem. Current data:

```
|emp_id | dates    | day_one |week_num |
 --------------------------------------
|    100|2021-01-01|     TRUE|        1|
|    100|2021-01-02|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-03|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-04|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-05|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-06|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-07|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-08|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-09|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-10|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-11|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-12|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-13|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-14|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-15|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-16|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-17|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-18|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-19|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-20|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-21|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-22|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-23|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-24|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-25|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-26|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-27|     NULL|     NULL|
|    100|2021-01-28|     NULL|     NULL|
 --------------------------------------
```

Desired output (repeating cycles):

```
|emp_id | dates    | day_one |week_num |
 --------------------------------------
|    100|2021-01-01|     TRUE|        1|
|    100|2021-01-02|     NULL|        1|
|    100|2021-01-03|     NULL|        1|
|    100|2021-01-04|     NULL|        1|
|    100|2021-01-05|     NULL|        1|
|    100|2021-01-06|     NULL|        1|
|    100|2021-01-07|     NULL|        1|
|    100|2021-01-08|     NULL|        2|
|    100|2021-01-09|     NULL|        2|
|    100|2021-01-10|     NULL|        2|
|    100|2021-01-11|     NULL|        2|
|    100|2021-01-12|     NULL|        2|
|    100|2021-01-13|     NULL|        2|
|    100|2021-01-14|     NULL|        2|
|    100|2021-01-15|     NULL|        1|
|    100|2021-01-16|     NULL|        1|
|    100|2021-01-17|     NULL|        1|
|    100|2021-01-18|     NULL|        1|
|    100|2021-01-19|     NULL|        1|
|    100|2021-01-20|     NULL|        1|
|    100|2021-01-21|     NULL|        1|
|    100|2021-01-22|     NULL|        2|
|    100|2021-01-23|     NULL|        2|
|    100|2021-01-24|     NULL|        2|
|    100|2021-01-25|     NULL|        2|
|    100|2021-01-26|     NULL|        2|
|    100|2021-01-27|     NULL|        2|
|    100|2021-01-28|     NULL|        2|
 --------------------------------------
```

Comment: You don't explain the problem here. What is the logic you are trying to achieve? What about what you have isn't working? What is your question? You haven't asked one.

Comment: _where weeks are added based off the day_one column_ Nothing in your code refers to this column. Is it actually meaningful or is your code making an assumption that you did not express or document? Are there gaps in the dates? Do the dates span a year boundary? Seems like a combination of row_number and modulo might work.

Comment: *"The lag/lead becomes very inefficient"* Why do you say `LAG`/`LEAD` is inefficient? It's actually one of the far more efficient operators; way more so than a self join using something like `ROW_NUMBER` for example. *"See desired output"* That doesn't tell me what the logic is... That's like showing me an apple and a pie and saying "Make it" with no instructions... *" I don’t see how your comment or downvoting helps anyone."* Where did I say I downvoted? Downvotes are anonymous, so where are you seeing data that says I voted? I might have to let them know the data is wrong.

Comment: @SMor it is how the data was. I created the week_num column from that to start with lag/lead. No gaps in dates.

Comment: If you don't want to explain the problem, that's ok too, @d789w , but it's very likely why you have received 2 downvotes, and could therefore result in your question being closed. Help us help you... We aren't paid to help you, we're using our free time to help you, for free. If you won't take the time to explain the problem, you'll find many others won't put the time in to answer your (unasked) question(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- PLEASE PROVIDE SET UP SCRIPT FOR SAMPLE DATA IN FUTURE POSTS

CREATE TABLE #table1
(
   emp_id   INT
  ,dates    DATE 
  ,day_one  VARCHAR(9)
  ,week_num_expected INT
);

INSERT INTO #table1(emp_id,dates,day_one,week_num_expected) VALUES
 (100,'2021-01-01','TRUE',1),(100,'2021-01-02',NULL,1),(100,'2021-01-03',NULL,1),(100,'2021-01-04',NULL,1)
,(100,'2021-01-05',NULL,1),(100,'2021-01-06',NULL,1),(100,'2021-01-07',NULL,1),(100,'2021-01-08',NULL,2)
,(100,'2021-01-09',NULL,2),(100,'2021-01-10',NULL,2),(100,'2021-01-11',NULL,2),(100,'2021-01-12',NULL,2)
,(100,'2021-01-13',NULL,2),(100,'2021-01-14',NULL,2),(100,'2021-01-15',NULL,1),(100,'2021-01-16',NULL,1)
,(100,'2021-01-17',NULL,1),(100,'2021-01-18',NULL,1),(100,'2021-01-19',NULL,1),(100,'2021-01-20',NULL,1)
,(100,'2021-01-21',NULL,1),(100,'2021-01-22',NULL,2),(100,'2021-01-23',NULL,2),(100,'2021-01-24',NULL,2)
,(100,'2021-01-25',NULL,2),(100,'2021-01-26',NULL,2),(100,'2021-01-27',NULL,2),(100,'2021-01-28',NULL,2);


-- MAYBE ??
SELECT
  emp_id,
  dates,
  day_one,
  week_num_expected,
  CASE
    WHEN (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dates ASC) - 1) / 7 = 0
    OR
    ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dates ASC) - 1) / 7) % 2 = 0 
    THEN 1
    ELSE 2
  END AS week_num_by_code

FROM #table1

DROP TABLE #table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided no gaps in dates and seven days a week

```
select 
    emp_id,
    dates,
    day_one,
    datediff(day,
         (select top(1) dates 
          from table1 t2
          where t2.emp_id = t1.emp_id and t2.day_one='TRUE'
          order by t2.dates),
         dates) % 7 + 1  
from table1 t;
```